# for loop unexpectedly breaks due to a function which uses pointer to a structure

Tags: c, for-loop, data-structures, stack, structure

whenever i try to use the following code in c the for loop breaks after one iteration and i cannot figure out why exactly.If not using for loop then it works fine which i did tested.Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stack 
{
    int top;
    int n;
    char *arr;
};

void push(struct stack *ptr,char x);

int main(){
    struct stack chs;
    struct stack *ptr;
    ptr = &chs;
    ptr->top=-1;
    printf("enter the size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d",&ptr->n);
    int size = ptr->n;
    for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
        printf("test iteration ");
        push(ptr,'a');
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void push(struct stack *ptr,char x){
    if(ptr->top >= (ptr->n-1)){
        printf("\nstack overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        ptr->top = (ptr->top) + 1;
        ptr->arr[(ptr->top)] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `char *arr` element of your structure is uninitialized so `ptr->arr[(ptr->top)]` is an undefined reference. The behavior at that point is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, member `arr` is never initialized to point to anything.  You can correct the problem by modifying your code to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stack 
{
    int top;
    int n;
    char *arr;
};

void push(struct stack *ptr,char x);

int main(){
    struct stack chs;
    struct stack *ptr;
    ptr = &chs;
    ptr->top=-1;
    printf("enter the size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d",&ptr->n);
    int size = ptr->n;

    char chs_arr[size]; // Variable-sized array based on input

    ptr->arr = chs_arr; // Set pointer member arr to point to array created.

    for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
        printf("test iteration ");
        push(ptr,'a');
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void push(struct stack *ptr,char x){
    if(ptr->top >= (ptr->n-1)){
        printf("\nstack overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        ptr->top = (ptr->top) + 1;
        ptr->arr[(ptr->top)] = x;
    }
}
```